# rails form info received but didn't save in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem

I've been trying for different solutions for the entire day. But nothing seems to work

Background info: For my app, users can upload images and each image can have many users. So it's a many-to-many-association through: . **The problem I'm encountering is that the info/data received from the form doesn't save in the database.**

I'm using the cocoon gem. When upload the image, I'm able to add and remove the users field in the frontend. When I upload the image, and select user1 and user2, debugger showed me that user_id1 and user_id2 are received. After submitting, I use rails console to check image.users. But it's empty, there're no users associate with the image. I did a lot of researching,and tried many different ways but nothing seems to work.

Debugger showing that the user_ids are received from the form.

```html
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/q52XogfTcEqCLap3K5C4B4I1gNYQGfBJOynNvdIXUE3ViVnRM+2JcksmaAwCWzBXw2kSOqOR+W25pefgBRRGw==", "image"=>{"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f49998bd320 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170103-11352-qmm06k.png>, @original_filename="erincolor4.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image[picture]\"; filename=\"erincolor4.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "image_users_attributes"=>{"1483469430746"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1483469434072"=>{"user_id"=>"9", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Upload", "controller"=>"images", "action"=>"create"}
```

I suspect the problem is not the form, but  either it's the model or controller.

```html
#Image model
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :picture, :image_users_attributes, :user_id
  has_many :image_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :image_users 


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :image_users, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  mount_uploader :picture, ImageUploader
  
  validates :picture,  presence: true
  validates_associated :image_users

end 
    
                                                              
                               
#User model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  
  has_many :image_users
  has_many :images, through: :image_users 
end 



#ImageUser model
class ImageUser < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :image
  
  
end
```

Image Controller

```html
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  
  before_action :set_image, only: [:show, :destroy, :edit, :update]
  before_action :require_user, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  
  def new 
    @image = Image.new
    
  end 
  
  def create 
    debugger
    @image = Image.new(image_params)
    if @image.save 
      flash[:success]="Image saved"
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else 
      render'new'
    end 
  end 

 ...........
  
private
  
  def image_params 
    params.require(:image).permit(:picture, image_users_attributes:[:id, :user_id, :_destroy])
  end 
  
  
  def set_image
    @image =Image.find(params[:id]) 
  end 
  

end
```

Form view:

```html
<%= form_for @image do |f|%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png'%>
    </div>
    <div id='image_users'>
      <%= f.fields_for :image_users do |u| %>
        <%=render 'image_user_fields', :f => u %>
      <% end %> 
      <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add user', f, :image_users %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit 'Upload' %>

<% end %>
  
#nested form
 <div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content,"Stylist" %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id,:username, :prompt => "  "  %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove stylist", f %>
  
</div>
```

I'm using cloud9 IDE

Comment: What gem are you using for storing images ?

Comment: i use gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick' for the images

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. As I watch videos, I saw attr_accessible, however when i run the server, it threw me an error and suggested attr_accessor. So I changed it to attr_accessor. Don't make this silly mistake. But if anyone can tell me why that attr_accessor made my code not work, that would be fantastic :)

Comment: what rails version are you running?